# Exception occured with replaceItem and date value

Tags: xpages

I am getting the following error when trying to set a date value using @Date value with replaceItemValue.

The error I am getting occurs on the last line of code here:

```
var dt = @Date(2012,1,1);
docContractor.replaceItemValue("NewField","Hello World");
docContractor.replaceItemValue("ContractorStartDateTime",dt);
```

The error is:

Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=21, col=31: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.replaceItemValue(string, Date) null

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works:

```
docContractor.replaceItemValue("ContractorStartDateTime", session.createDateTime("Today"));
```

You can find more examples in the Notes and Domino App Dev wiki: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/NotesDateTime_sample_JavaScript_code_for_XPages

Comment: Doesn't that leave an unrecycled NotesDateTime object behind?

Comment: But this only creates the Date. How can i create Datetime? i dont want "Today 12" as i see in examples i want to save the current datetime every time. any ideas? (also i dont want it to be saved as string but as Date in a Date/Time field in a Notes form)

Comment: Mike, please create a new question for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a NotesDateTime object instead? 
Or use toString ()